# Anonymous Inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class

```
class One {
Two two() {
    return new Two() {
        Two(){}
        Two(String s) {
            System.out.println("s= "+s);
        }
    };
    }
}

class Ajay {
    public static void main(String ...strings ){
        One one=new One();
        System.out.println(one.two());
    }
}
```

The above sample code cannot be compiled.It says "Two cannot be resolved".
What is the problem in this code??

Comment: Is there any problem with the code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Two() {
    Two(){}
    Two(String s) {
        System.out.println("s= "+s);
    }
};
```

An anonymous inner class is called anonymous because it doesn't have its own name and has to be referred to by the name of the base-class or interface it extends/implements.

In your example you create an anonymous subclass of `Two` so `Two` has to be declared somewhere either as a class or interface. If the class Two is already declared you either don't have it on your classpath or forgot to import it.

Comment: Thanx.I forgot to declare the class Two.infact i did not know that the class Two should be declared because the book iam refering doesn't  mention this..

Answer (score 1):

you are creating

`new Two()` so there must be a valid class in classpath.

make it

```
class Two{

}

class One {
Two two() {
    return new Two() {
//        Two(){}
//        Two(String s) {
//            System.out.println("s= "+s);
//        }//you can't override constuctors
    };
    }
}
```

or on left side of new there must be super class or interface to make it working

Comment: @jigar...no he is using next-generation-dynamic-class-generation which automatically creates any class that is not in the classpath and also creates sensible methods for it;)

Comment: Since`Two` is actually being implemented as an anonymous inner class, it might make more sense to declare it as an interface or abstract class rather than a class.

Comment: @MAK *being implemented as an anonymous inner class* for the shown code only

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the `Two` class. You declared class `One` and private member `two`, where `two` is object of `Two` class which you tried to initialize by anonymous construction.

Comment: `two` is not declared private

Comment: `Two(){}` is the constructor where as `Two two(){}` is a method of class `One`.