# java function definition with object creation

Tags: java, function, comparator

In the below code, I want to understand what does the Collections.sort function is doing. What does this means

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() { a complete java function });
```

I understand that `new Comparator()` means a class object, but what is the purpose of the function block here, and what we call it in java.

Thanks.

```
/**
     * Sorts/shuffles the given list according to the current sending queue 
     * mode. The list can contain either Message or Tuple<Message, Connection> 
     * objects. Other objects cause error. 
     * @param list The list to sort or shuffle
     * @return The sorted/shuffled list
     */
    @SuppressWarnings(value = "unchecked") /* ugly way to make this generic */
    protected List sortByQueueMode(List list) {
        switch (sendQueueMode) {

    case Q_MODE_RANDOM:
        Collections.shuffle(list, new Random(SimClock.getIntTime()));
        break;
    case Q_MODE_FIFO:
        Collections.sort(list, 
                new Comparator() {
            /** Compares two tuples by their messages' receiving time */
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                double diff;
                Message m1, m2;

                if (o1 instanceof Tuple) {
                    m1 = ((Tuple<Message, Connection>)o1).getKey();
                    m2 = ((Tuple<Message, Connection>)o2).getKey();
                }
                else if (o1 instanceof Message) {
                    m1 = (Message)o1;
                    m2 = (Message)o2;
                }
                else {
                    throw new SimError("Invalid type of objects in " + 
                            "the list");
                }

                diff = m1.getReceiveTime() - m2.getReceiveTime();
                if (diff == 0) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return (diff < 0 ? -1 : 1);
            }
        });
        break;
    /* add more queue modes here */
    default:
        throw new SimError("Unknown queue mode " + sendQueueMode);
    }

    return list;
}
```

I finally got he understanding of comparator. This simple example would help:

```
 Collections.sort(ls, new Comparator() 
                           {

                            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) 
                            {
                            String sa = (String)o1;
                            String sb = (String)o2;

                            int v = sa.compareTo(sb);

                            return v;           

                                // it can also return 0, and 1
                            }
                           }    
                    );
```

Comment: Is this means sorting depends on what the function is returning? So what would be the sorting behavior in above lines if the function return -1, or 0, or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method sorts the collection given as the parameter. By default the *natural order* of the collection is used. The natural order is defined by the objects in the collection. 
For example, when you have a collection of `String`s, the sort method sorts this collection in the alphabetical order of the Strings. How does the `sort` method knows that it has to sort alphabetically? It used the compareTo method in the `String` class. `compareTo` compares the current object (`this`) with another objects and decides which comes first between these two. Using `compareTo` on all the items in the list, `sort` determines the correct order.

So compareTo determines the *natural order* of an object.

What if you want some other ordering other than the natural order? Say you want to sort a list of Strings in reverse alphabetical order?

You can do that by [another (overloaded) variant of the sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). This variant accepts a second parameter, which is a instance of the Comparator interface.

So, you have to write your own class that implements [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and so that has its own `compareTo` method. The sort method then uses this `compareTo` rather than the `compareTo` in the object in the collection (`String`).

So you say

```
class MyStringComparator<String> implements Comparator
{
    public int compareTo(String a, String b)
    {
        return a.compareTo(b) * -1; //Reverse the order. 
                                    //The logic can be as complex as your need is
    }
}
```

and then

```
MyStringComparator myStringComparator = new MyStringComparator();
Collections.sort(myStringList, myStringComparator);
```

or

Collections.sort(myStringList, new MyStringComparator(););

See [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

If the `MyStringComparator` is going to be used only for this case, you would not want to create an separate class, give it a name, a file and so on. All you need is a something temporary that you can forget after the sort.

So instead of writing all the code, you can say:

```
Collections.sort(myStringList, new Comparator()
                               {
                                   public int compareTo(String a, String b)
                                   {
                                       return a.compareTo(b) * -1; 
                                   }
                               }
               );
```

See, the second parameter is the class definition itself.

This is called an [anonymous inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153221/anonymous-inner-class). A kind of use and throw class, for such situations. You will see a lot of anonymous inner class in Swing event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

That's called an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).
It's used to pass functions as parameters, since Java does not support function pointers.

Comment: thanks. so what this function is performing in the above code?

Comment: It's basically a callback.  It compares two objects.

Comment: so when the function in the curly braces will return a value, where that value will be passed

Comment: @OsmanKhalid: To whatever called the function.  Just like any other function.  In this case, something in `sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is defining your own class, without giving it a name; that is, it's an anonymous class.  This class `extends` `Comparator`, which means that it's just like `Comparator`, but with something that's changed or extra (it's not compulsory to have something that's changed or extra when you extend a class, but there's not much point in extending a class if you're not going to change something).

In this case, your anonymous class has its own method called `compare`, which describes how to compare two objects and find out which one should appear first in some order.

The next thing you do is to make an object from your class - the `new` keyword does that.

Lastly, the object that you created gets passed to `Collections.sort`.  This, unsurprisingly, sorts your list, but does so with the ordering implied by your anonymous class; that is, it calls the `compare` method inside your anonymous class, whenever it needs to decide which of two objects should appear first in the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically re-hashing what other's have said, but I think it can be explained in simpler terms.

Firstly:

`Collections.sort` takes a `Comparator`, which defines how objects should be compared to one another.  One type of `Comparator` might compare `Integer` numerically based on their values.  Another type of `Comparator` might compare `String` alphabetically based on their characters.

Your `Comparator` compares `Tuple` and `Message` based on their `receiveTime`.

Secondly:

`Comparator` is an interface which has one method called `compare(Object, Object)`.  Java allows you to define concrete classes for interfaces on the fly in the form of ***anonymous classes***.

An anonymous class that implements an interface simply defines the methods for that interface "on the fly" (i.e. in the middle of some other code; not in it's own `.class` file).  Your example simply defines the `compare(Object, Object)` method on the fly.